# Задача на многопоточность из книги Гослинга

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть задача:

> Напишите программу, которая каждую секунду отображает на экране данные
> о времени, прошедшем от начала сессии, а другой её поток выводит
> сообщение каждые 5 секунд. Предусмотрите возможность ежесекундного
> оповещения потока, воспроизводящего сообщение, потоком, отсчитывающим
> время. Не внося изменений в код потока-"хронометра" , добавьте ещё
> один поток, который выводит на экран другое сообщение каждые 7 секунд.

Предполагается использование методов wait(), notifyAll().

Мое решение (см. ниже) работает, но только частично. А именно: сообщение из потока t1 выводиться через 5 секунд работы таймера в потоке main, но тлько один раз, а должно бы каждые 5 секунд. В чем проблема?

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Chronometr my=new Chronometr();
        Runnable t1=new Messenger(5, my);
        new Thread(t1, "t1").start();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            
            synchronized(my) {
                
                Chronometr.time+=1;
                System.out.println(Chronometr.time);
                my.notifyAll();
                //my.wait();
                }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        
        
        }
    }
    
class Chronometr {
    static int time=0;
    public void timeCount() throws InterruptedException {
         
    }
}   
class Messenger implements Runnable{
    int time;
    public Chronometr ch;
    Messenger(int time, Chronometr ch) {
        this.time=time;
        this.ch=ch;
    }
    public void waitForTime() {
        
        synchronized (ch) { 
            
            try{
                while (Chronometr.time%time!=0)
                    {ch.wait();
                    
                    }
                System.out.println("Thread "+this.time);
                
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }} 
        /*try{
        Thread.sleep(time*1000);}
        catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }*/
    public void run()  {
        waitForTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что сразу после того, как условие выполнилось и время распечаталось, ваш поток заканчивает свое выполнение.

**Обновление**

[[@hbadger](/users/20678/hbadger)](/users/20678/hbadger) Вам нужен еще один цикл, внешний относительно while с хронометром. И неплохо бы предусмотреть политики прерывания потока, например по флагу.

Comment: спасибо, что-то подобное я и думала. а как бы вы реализовали, чтобы поток не завершался после выполнения условия, а снова входил в режим ожидания?
я пробовала с помощью различных циклов, но эффект был "неудовлетворительный" - по факту просто сообщение от потока t1 выводлось много раз подряд.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Ну я вот так решил

```
public class App {

    public App(int lifetime) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        T1 t1 = new T1(a);
        T2 t2 = new T2(a, "Test!");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(lifetime * 1000+100);
        t1.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new App(15);
    }

    class T1 extends Thread {

        private A app;

        public T1(A app) {
            this.app = app;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                this.app.add();
            }
        }
    }

    class T2 extends Thread {

        private A app;
        private String message;

        public T2(A app, String message) {
            this.app = app;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                int n;
                try {
                    n = app.last();
                    System.out.println(n);
                    // это можно вынести в отдельный поток
                    if (n % 5 == 0)
                        System.out.println(message);
                    /*if (n % 7 == 0)
                        System.out.println(message);*/
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class A {

        private int d = 0;

        public synchronized void add() {
            this.d++;
            notify();
        }

        public synchronized int last() throws InterruptedException {
            wait();
            return this.d;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Test!
6
7
8
9
10
Test!
11
12
13
14
15
Test!
```

Answer (score 0):

Программа работает. Решил таким образом:

```
public class Test {
    static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Worker worker = new Worker();
        Thread clocker = new Thread(new Clock(worker));
        Thread messager = new Thread(new Messanger(worker));
        clocker.start();
        messager.start();
    }
}

class Worker {
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;

    public void clock() {
        synchronized (Test.lock) {
            System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            seconds++;
            if (seconds == 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
            }
            while (seconds % 5 == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                    Test.lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            Test.lock.notify();
        }
    }

    public void message() {
        synchronized (Test.lock) {
            while (seconds % 5 != 0) {
                try {
                    Test.lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            seconds++;
            System.out.println("MESSAGE!!!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            Test.lock.notify();
        }
    }
}


class Clock implements Runnable {
    Worker worker;

    public Clock(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            worker.clock();
        }
    }
}

class Messanger implements Runnable {
    Worker worker;

    public Messanger(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            worker.message();
        }
    }
}
```

Выход:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
0:5
MESSAGE!!!
0:6
0:7
0:8
0:9
0:10
MESSAGE!!!
0:11
0:12
0:13
0:14
0:15
MESSAGE!!!
0:16
0:17
0:18
0:19
```