# Запутался в многопоточности, почему Потоки ушли в deadlock?

Tags: java, многопоточность

пытаюсь разобраться в многопочности, решил порешать задачи  - взял [вот эту:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338205/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)

для 2х потоков решил, решение:

```
public class App {
    private final static int WAIT_5_SECONDS = 5;
    private final static int WAIT_7_SECONDS = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Chronometr chrono = new Chronometr();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(chrono, "Thread1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Message("TEST", chrono, WAIT_5_SECONDS), "Thread2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Message("TEST 7", chrono, WAIT_7_SECONDS), "Thread3");
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        //thread3.start(); //если запустить, то получаю deadlock

    }

}


class Message  implements Runnable{
    private final String text;
    private final Chronometr chrono;
    private final int waitTime;

    public Message(String text, Chronometr chronometr, int waitTime) {
        this.text = text;
        this.chrono = chronometr;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(chrono){
            try {
                while(true){
                    if (chrono.getCurrentSeconds() % waitTime == 0 && chrono.getCurrentSeconds() - waitTime >= 0) {
                       System.out.println(text);                        
                                    
                    }
                    chrono.notifyAll();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    chrono.wait();              
                    
                 }

                 
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                        System.out.println("I'm finished");
                    }
        
    }
}
}

class Chronometr implements Runnable {
    volatile private int currentSeconds = 0;
    boolean isStop = false;

    

    public void setStop(boolean isStop) {
        this.isStop = isStop;
    }

    public int getCurrentSeconds() {
        return this.currentSeconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
        try {
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(++currentSeconds);
                this.notifyAll();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                this.wait();
            }
             
        }
        catch (InterruptedException exp) {
            System.out.println("I'M end");
        }
        
    }
    }
  
}
```

Если запустить 3й поток, получаю deadlock. Но почему? разве notifyAll() не должен был разбутить все уснувшие потоки?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, никакого deadlock нет.
notifyAll() оповещает все потоки, дальше кто первый получил монитор тот и работает, так как в первом потоке я записал Thread.sleep(1000) - тем самым я фактически лешил его шанса получить монитор. Вынес Thread.sleep из synchronized блока и все заработало.